# RGB Serial Issue

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make a Arduino program where it receives signals from the Serial monitor and then lights LED's accordingly, i have it set up with RGB. But I have a problem where all three LED's light like the blue one only should. here is my code:

```
#define SENSOR 0   
#define R_LED 11
#define G_LED 10
#define B_LED 9
#define BUTTON 12
int val = 0;
int times = 0;
int btn = LOW;
int old_btn = LOW;
int state = 0;
int r = 0;
int g = 0;
int b = 0;
byte inByte = 0;
char buffer[5];
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
  val = analogRead(SENSOR);
  Serial.println(val);
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    inByte = Serial.read();
    if (inByte == '#') {
      r = Serial.read() + 1;
      r = r * 25;
      g = Serial.read() + 1;
      g = g * 25;
      b = Serial.read() + 1;
      b = b * 25;
    }
  }   
  btn = digitalRead(BUTTON);
  if ((btn == HIGH) && (old_btn == LOW)){
    state = 1 - state;
  }
  old_btn = btn;
  if (state == 1){
    analogWrite(R_LED, r);
    analogWrite(G_LED, g);
    analogWrite(B_LED, b);
  }else{
    analogWrite(R_LED, 0);
    analogWrite(G_LED, 0);
    analogWrite(B_LED, 0);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

Note: I am sure it is a coding issue, not a mechanical one,for your information.

Comment: You're more likely to get a qualified answer here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but i don't think so, i have checked and rechecked, it is not a mechanical issue, it is a coding one.

Comment: It's not hardware vs. software issue - it's about the number of arduino users on that site vs. this one. Arduino people hang out there.

Comment: oh, maybe I will try that then.

Comment: Actually you are always better off posting on the Arduino forums (http://arduino.cc/forum/) - much more active community.

Comment: OK skinny, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing correctly, some code such as `#987` will be sent on the serial monitor every time you want the color to change, correct? In that case, the issue is that when you do `r = Serial.read() + 1;` (and the same goes for `b` and `g`), `Serial.read()` is returning the ASCII code for a character from `'0'` through `'9'` (48 - 57). Try this:

```
  r = Serial.read() - '0' + 1;
  r = r * 25;
  g = Serial.read() - '0' + 1;
  g = g * 25;
  b = Serial.read() - '0' + 1;
  b = b * 25;
```

This will subtract the ASCII code for `'0'` first, so the numbers will be in the proper 0-9 range.

Comment: You can also use `Serial.parseInt()`

Comment: Good idea, @Fuzzyfelt, although SuperKael would have to add spaces between the digits to prevent it from parsing as one three digit int.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're doing the identical thing to all three lights.

Why would you expect blue to behave differently?

```
analogWrite(R_LED, r);
analogWrite(G_LED, g);
analogWrite(B_LED, b);
```

Comment: because the get different signals from the serial, so they should be different brightnesses.